# Identify actual mime type based on content of attachments NOT from content-type value

Tags: perl, email, mime-types, email-attachments

I have an email in which content-type values are **changed/manipulated** in header.

How can i know actual content type of attachment, by analyzing the content data. Encoding is base-64.

Comment: You might find the module [File::LibMagic](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::LibMagic) useful

Comment: Is the content-type in your headers the literal string `changed/manipulated`?

Comment: @simbabque no, i mean the values are altered or changed by any man (OR woman :P) in middle of communication